# Java: replace switch with lambdas. Worth it?

Tags: java, coding-style

Using blocks of code with switch or if is a common thing when checking for events. It can be clean code when made simple, but still seems to have more lines than needed, and could be simplified using lambdas.

Block with if:

```
if(action == ACTION_1){
    doAction1();
} else if(action == ACTION_2){
    doAction2();
} else {
    doDefaultAction();
}
```

Block with switch:

```
switch(action){
    case ACTION_1:
        doAction1();
        break;
    case ACTION_2:
        doAction2();
        break;
    default:
        doDefaultAction();
}
```

Block with lambdas using the utility class `With` below:

```
with(action)
    .when(ACTION_1, this::doAction1)
    .when(ACTION_2, this::doAction2)
    .byDefault(this::doDefaultAction)
```

Using lambdas has less code, but the question is: is it easier to read than the others? Easier to maintain? Regarding performance lambdas is the worst, but for cases where performance is not important the lambdas version is shorter than the switch/if blocks.

So, how do you see it? Maybe there is a Kotlin way shorter than this, I try to focus on java only, I love Kotlin but the compilation is still too slow for my projects.

A similar utility class could be used when the block must return a specific value.

FYI, the class for the lambdas is here, I didn't check for errors, just made it quickly for this example:

```
public class With<T> {

    private final T id;
    private boolean actionFound;

    private With(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static <T> With<T> with(T id) {
        return new With<>(id);
    }

    public With<T> when(T expectedId, Action action) {
        if (!actionFound && id == expectedId) {
            actionFound = true;
            action.execute();
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void byDefault(Action action) {
        if (!actionFound) {
            action.execute();
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Action {
        void execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Certainly looks neater - but it is much less efficient. Whilst a `switch` is simply a jump table in bytecode; your lambda approach must evaluate as many times as there are options every time. Only you can decide whether this consideration matters to you.

Comment: Also, this - `id == expectedId` - is an AWFUL idea. You know why...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Agree with you, it is less efficient, and comparing using `==` is not good for objects, but it does the same than the `switch` so the comparation should not be a problem in this case

Comment: "but it does the same than the switch" bubble sort does the same as other sorting algorithms; but Java doesn't use bubble sort when you invoke `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort`... Not all correct algorithms are equal.

Comment: Wrong - this is why I say it's an awful idea. Whilst a switch will _unbox_ primitives your generics will _box_ them - this will mean that even any [`-128 < int < 127`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) won't work as you expect. And don't forget `switch` supports `String`.

Comment: You are right, it does not exactly the same, both do same thing in different ways. Regarding generics, interesting comment about boxing, should take into account, the comparation is by reference using `if_acmpne` instruction but need to be sure it uses the cache for frequently occurring values. Thanks man!

Comment: The point is that whilst `Integer.valueOf(1) == Integer.valueOf(1)` will work, `Integer.valueOf(1_000) == Integer.valueOf(1_000)` will not. The switch statement **will not work** for values outside of the cached range. This isn't a performance concern, it's a correctness concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a couple has said, replacing `switch` with compounded methods is less efficient.  Depending on your use-case, it might even be worth it to use your implementation.

Funnily enough, Oracle is actually planning to implement lambdas within `switch` statements, as seen in [this recent JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325).

Example:

```
String formatted = switch (s) {
    case null -> "(null)";
    case "" -> "(empty)";
    default -> s;
}
```

Comment: You are right about performance, thanks a lot for the link to the JEP! Amazing

Comment: What LISP already has since more than 50 years (decent conditional constructs for expressions, not only statements), is finally coming to Java. A readable, much more flexible replacement for the ternary operator!

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Hallelujah!

Comment: @IgnacioTomasCrespo And one more disadvantage of your construct: compilers are very smart about understanding the control flow of `if` and `switch` statements: they can identify dead code, warn about incomplete case lists and so on. I don't think that will be possible with your class.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff good point, another disadvantage to take into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The switch is more flexible in that you can call functions with varying numbers of arguments, or call more than one function. You can also more easily denote when two cases lead to the same action. The fact that it's faster is just a bonus.

So in that sense I'm not sure what your `With` class is really adding.

However, switch has a limited number of types that it can work with. Perhaps your `With` class would prove to be more useful if you were to pass it predicates rather than performing simple reference equality, for example:

```
public With<T> when(Predicate<T> expected, Action action) {
    if (!actionFound && expected.test(id)) {
        actionFound = true;
        action.execute();
    }
    return this;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
final String test = "test";

with(test)
    .when(String::isEmpty,      this::doAction1)
    .when(s -> s.length() == 3, this::doAction2)
    .byDefault(this::doDefaultAction);
```

Comment: You are right, switch is more flexible, many cases can be combined into one. In this case the `With` class has no advantage at all. I'm interested in your idea with predicates, could you give me an example?

Comment: @IgnacioTomasCrespo Sure, I have added an example.

Comment: Wow, this is getting better. I like using predicates for the conditions. Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 2):

> replace switch with lambdas. Worth it?

No.

Because in an OO language the replacemenst for a `switch` or an `if`/`else` cascade is *polymorphism*, not "fluent API".

Comment: Totally agree about polymorphism and switch statements. Should be the first thing to take into account. But IMHO in some cases is more boilerplate and the pattern doesn't help.

Comment: @IgnacioTomasCrespo separating the *configuration* code from the *execution* code is the my  personal killer feature of polymorphism. I never had a situation where it hasn't been worth the effort...

Answer (score 1):

One option to do this is to declare `static final Map<T, Action> EXPECTED_ID_TO_ACTION`. Then you just can `EXPECTED_ID_TO_ACTION.getOrDefault(actionId, DEFAULT_ACTION).execute()`, turning ugly `switch` or multiple `if`s into one-liner.

Comment: Still **much** worse than a `switch` - but better than the suggested approach.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Disagree. Multiple `case` blocks (> 10) in `switch` look ugly. Also, this approach allows to change branching behavior at runtime if needed.

Comment: Indeed - thanks @JacobG. A bytecode jump table will eat a `Map` for breakfast.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You are right, performance vise it's still much slower than `switch` (if we are talking about resonable number of branches). Thanks for pointing this out, answer is edited.